# shall I use multiple separate tables or one table with multiple partitions in oracle

Tags: oracle, data-storage, database-partitioning

I have an entity lets call it `Response`, and another entity called `ResponseType`, `Response` entity contains the `ResponseType`.
So when I am building the physical model I confused with how to implement it.
I have two options:

1. I can create a `Response` table for each of `ResponseType`.
2. I can create a Global `Response` table with a `ResponseType` Column and create a partition for each `ResponseType`.

Note that, `Response` Entity is same for each of `ResponseType`. Each `ResponseType` is equivalent.

What is your idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to create separate tables.

You would normally create a `Response` table, a `ResponseType` table, and create a foreign key between the two.  Something like

```
CREATE TABLE ResponseType (
  ResponseTypeId NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  <<other columns>>
);

CREATE TABLE Response (
  ResponseId     NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  ResponseTypeId NUMBER REFERENCES ResponseType( ResponseTypeId ),
  <<other columns>>
);
```

If you have the Enterprise Edition and you have also licensed the partitioning option and your queries will always specify a `ResponseTypeId` when querying the `Response` table and will generally want to read all the `Response` rows for a particular `ResponseTypeId` rather than using an index, there may be performance benefits to partitioning the `Response` table.  But that's a rather large number of `if` statements.